# Making a Mean stack application with angular cli?

Tags: mean-stack, angular-cli

I am a beginner to Angular2.

This is the article I was following:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/mean-app-with-angular-2-and-the-angular-cli

Tl;dr: ng new app, ng serve, npm install express etc, create server files, ng build and finally node express.js to serve index.html from dist

My problem with the app build in this article is that it serves from dist which means I would have to stop the server, run a new build and restart the server on every change which is quite cumbersome from pov of a developer. I want my changes to the client side to be reflected on each refresh.

Can someone point me in the right direction so as to achieve this? Or let me know how to to get the architecture right even if it means starting from scratch

PS:I have been trying to modify this example to serve from development (src/) however so far am unsuccessful. The browser is unable to find dependencies, shows the "loading.." throws errors like "System is not defined" and "Syntax error '<'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your pain point. I've seen this tutorial and its fair up to some extent, but as you said there is no auto-refresh script written for changes. However, I have then decided to create my own repository for the MEAN stack project development. Check the following URL where I hosted my MEAN app including

- browser-sync
- gulp
- nodemon

https://github.com/darpanpathak/MEAN2-MarvelApp

This repository will help you a lot for starting MEAN stack application with angular2.

thumbs up if you are looking for the same.

Answer (score 1):

> Tl;dr: ng new app, ng serve, npm install express etc, create server
>   files, ng build and finally node express.js to serve index.html from
>   dist

To make webpack to watch your changes during development you just have to add `--watch` when you build your app. So you should type something like this in a console terminal:

```
ng build --watch
```

And then run your server:

```
node server.js
```

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem as well, so I wrote a little post about it.
You can find the detailed solution [here](https://medium.com/@danielkagan/serve-mean-stack-using-angular-cli-f39b33dbad64).

In summary, what worked for me is to use different ports for the server and client, and configure my `npm start` command to run both server & client in parallel.
You will have hot reloading (when you change the client code, it will refresh the web browser instantly), and the web page will call your server API.

BTW, I couldn't make `ng build --watch` to work, so I had to think about this workaround.